# why is ground needed to be common in i2c communication?

Tags: i2c

I'm using i2c  for communication between arduino and SBT-150 thrusters , but the problem is that thrusters use 24V and arduino use 5V. So, i want to somehow isolate the two grounds for protection of my arduino.

Comment: Which is your question: why does ground need to be common, or how can you isolate one of the devices?

Comment: You really don't have a very good case for adding isolation here. Connect the grounds and make your life substantially easier.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a circuit without two connections, and for I2C, one of those connections is ground.

It's possible to galvanically isolate I2C with a [bit of circuitry](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10364.pdf):

[image: http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10364.pdf]

If you build the above circuit (for SDA and another for SCL) you don't need to connect the grounds.

Having the grounds common provides an enabling factor for disaster but does not really invite it with open arms. If you had long wires and a lot of noise there might be more justification.